# Firebase autenticación SMS

Tags: ionic, firebase-auth

Tengo un problema estoy utilizando ionic 5 + firebase autenticación SMS

la autenticación de firebase mediante sms funciona bien en la plataforma android, el problema es con IOS cuando aplico las dos funciones siguientes, me redirecciona a una captcha donde hago la verificación, pero no sigue el resto del proceso

```
this.fa.verifyPhoneNumber(telephone, 30000)
  .then((verficationID) => {
    this.user.verificationID = verficationID;
    if (verficationID) {
      
      this.navCtrl.navigateForward('/verification', navigationExtras);
    } else {
      this.toastCtrl.crearToast('Error', 'No se pudo Verificar El Nro de Telefono', 3000, 'bottom', 'danger');
    }

  })
  .catch((error) => {
    this.toastCtrl.crearToast('Error', error, 3000, 'bottom', 'danger');
  })



this.fa.signInWithVerificationId(user.verificationID, user.smscode(ESTE ES EL CODIGO DEL SMS que ingresa el usuario))
  .then((userReturn) => {

    if (userReturn == 'OK') {
      
        this.navCtrl.navigateRoot(['./tabs']);
      });

    }

  })
  .catch((error) => {
    this.toastCtrl.crearToast('Error', error, 3000, 'bottom', 'danger');
  })
```

Luego de esto aparece la verificacion captcha en IOS, verifica, pero no procede a ejecutar la ultima funcion para enviar el sms al telefono

Comment: agrega que te devuelve en ios por favor

Comment: Cuando ejecuta esta función 
signInWithVerificationId()

Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSNull length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1c6c48238

Comment: agrega el error en tu pregunta, ese error es por que no estas capturando bien una promesa parece, agrega la parte del código donde se genera.

Comment: Gracias, por tu ayuda ya pude solucionar, en ios la promesa no devuelve nada como en Android que si retorna la promesa en esa función.
Con eso pude autentificar en IOS